# Copiar de .txt para colar em software - Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

Boa noite prezados, como vao?
Essa é a primeira pergunta que faço referente ao meu primeiro projeto em Python.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde vou pegar algumas linhas de textos no .txt e enviar para um programa especifico que ira armazenar esse texto, consegui realizar essa automação assistindo a um video no YT, porem estou com um problema na parte de copiar e colar essas linhas. No video o Dev ensina o codigo utilizando o comando `linha.split` pois no txt dele cada linha tem 3 textos que ele vai inserir em capos diferentes: Campo 1, campo 2 e campo 3. Porem no meu caso eu tenho apenas um texto por linha.

Por conta disso eu nao consigo fazer com que a automacao pegue uma linha de cada vez e va iserindo no software. Do restante ja esta mapeado e funcionando mas o meu problema é encontrar o codigo que faça isso pra mim. Sou novato na area. Vou deixar meu codigo para entendimento.

````
from time import sleep

pyautogui.click(104, 30, duration=2)
pyautogui.click(96, 70, duration=1)

        # Copiar e colar - problema
with open('testes.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        chave = linha.split(',')[0]
        
pyautogui.click(874, 361, duration=2)
pyautogui.write(chave)
pyautogui.click(658, 400, duration=2)
pyautogui.click(679,444, duration=2)
sleep(1)```
 
Desde já, agradeço.
````

Comment: A chave só está definida dentro do ciclo. Tens que indentar o código em baixo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Nao sei bem o que seria indetar, mas vou procurar aqqui.

Comment: Opa, voltei aqui. Consegui entender sobre o identar o codigo, ainda precisei fazer algumas alteracoes.

Answer (score -2):

O codigo Final ficou assim:

````
    import pyautogui
    from time import sleep
    pyautogui.click(45, 34, duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.click(75, 69, duration=0.5)
    with open('testes.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
        for linha in arquivo:
            chave = linha.split(',')[0]
            pyautogui.click(479, 360, duration=1)
            pyautogui.write(chave)
            pyautogui.click(658, 400, duration=0.5)
            pyautogui.click(679, 444, duration=0.5)
            sleep(0.5)
            pyautogui.click(45, 34, duration=0.5)
            pyautogui.click(75, 69, duration=0.5)```

Ainda ficou faltando um condição para o loop parar sozinho, mas ja cumpriu o que eu queria.
````

Comment: Como assim parar sozinho? Ele para quando terminar.

Comment: No meu caso ele fica em loop, poq no txt tem 45 linhas com chaves de acesso de NFE. Quando ele termina de adicionar a linha de numero 45, ele volta e começa a adicionar tudo de novo. Linha1...2...3 e assim por diante.

Comment: Isso é impossível.